# What is the most efficient way to compare two arrays of booleans?

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I have an array `a` of 10 booleans (or equivalently the binary representation of a number < 1024). I want to compare this array to a large set of arrays `b[i]` of booleans of the same size in the following way:
The function `compare(a,b[i])` should return `true` if the elements of the array `a` are never  `true` when the element of at the same position in `b[i]` is `false`.

As an exemple in java

```
boolean compare(boolean a1, boolean a2){
for (int j = 0; j<10; j++) 
   if (a1[j] && !a2[j]) 
      return false;
return true;
}
```

Is there a better implementation of this function? If one consider the corresponding binary number to be the coefficients of the prime decomposition of a integer A1 (and A2), an equivalent function would be

```
boolean compare (int A1, int A2){
if (gcd(A1,A2)==A1) 
   return true;
else
   return false;
}
```

with for example, (http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/finding-greatest-common-divisor-recursively.html)

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
if (b==0) 
   return a;
else
   return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

but I don't think that this is more efficient (but I may be wrong).

Does anyone has an idea ? All suggestions are welcome!

EDIT: I will go back with some profiling later... Thanks for all your propositions!

Comment: There's only one way to know-- profile them!

Comment: And before you do that, profile the entire application to decide if it is actually worthwhile expending effort on optimizing this calculation.

Comment: It is conventional in Java to call the `compare` method `equals`, because `compareTo` is used for the notion of ordering rather than equality. Signature of the method has booleans rather than arrays of booleans as arguments, I guess this was a mistake. I don't know what are you representing by arrays of booleans, but most of the times those are bad, consider using bytes for space efficiency and possibly comparision speed. You could represent an array of 10 booleans with 2 bytes and compare them using `&` and `~` operators instead of ten comparisions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use integers instead of arrays, why not just:

```
return ((a1 & ~a2) == 0)
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure [`BitSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) is more efficient, but it should be on the short list of implementations to profile.

Answer (score 2):

If you could have those boolean arrays as integers instead, you could use bitwise operations:

```
boolean compare(int a1, int a2) {
  return (a1 | a2) == a2;
}
```

I think that should work...

Answer (score 2):

If you  have int representation of the data, you may use bitwise operators:

```
boolean compare(int a, int b) {
    int c = ~b ^ a;
    return c == 0;
}
```

If any ocurrence of *¬b[i] ^ a[i]* happens, *c* will not be zero.

Answer (score 1):

I might sound kinda off point. However, there seem to be a java inbuilt way of doing this.

```
java.util.Arrays.equals(blnArray1,blnArray2)
```

Reference: http://www.java-examples.com/compare-two-java-boolean-arrays-example

It works for me.